# bxSlider Images Custom Height and Width

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow, bxslider

I'm using bxslider, for my carousel images..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider4').bxSlider({
  slideWidth: 300,
  minSlides: 2,
  maxSlides: 3,
  moveSlides: 1,
  slideMargin: 10
 });
});


<div class="slider4">
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar1"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar2"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar3"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar4"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar5"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar6"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar7"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar8"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar9"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar10"></div>
</div>
```

This code came from the examples page of bxlider site. This is the one i'm using right now. I just noticed that when i resize my browser to smaller size, e.g 768, 480 and 320..

It's responsive but the images are chopped off and too small for 320px and 480px.

What i want is, If i re-size the browser to 480 or 320, it will show 2 images only. preserving the height and width of the images.  Any Ideas on how to do that?

Comment: as an alternative, i wrote some css codes using `!important` to set the height and width of the images --

Comment: what direction are the images in the ul ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bxslider has a responsive option you can set to false. This should stop resizing the slider.
Then you maybe could reload the slider with `reloadSlider()` on `resize()` so it would show less images.

like: http://jsfiddle.net/Lhz7qbzc/